# Ubuntu setting rfkill state requires privileges

Tags: rfkill

In the last update of Ubuntu, all the users who are not admin, are having a popup on login with the message

```
setting rfkill state requires privileges
```

and further requesting the admin password.

Answer (score 7):

Just for everyone interested, I solved it by adding those users to the groups `bluetooth` and `netdev`. I guess it doesn't bring any security issues

```
sudo usermod -a -G bluetooth <user>
sudo usermod -a -G netdev <user>
```

[`rfkill`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/rfkill.8.html) is a tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices.

Comment: On Linux Mint 21 `netdev` seems to be enough